# Cross platform drive partition analyzer

Tags: windows, osx, cross-platform, windows-10, disk-analysis

I've just restored a junked MacBook to add to my several existing Windows PCs. In the process of getting things working I fiddled with a couple of hard drives trying to add partitions of various kinds which I can no longer recall.

Well few people will have that same use case but there will be many other use cases.

So this has revealed that the standard partitioning apps with Windows 10 and Max OS X El Capitan don't seem to be able to tell me everything about the various partitioning schemes and filesystems on each drive.

Has somebody created a cross platform app that's available for at least Mac and Windows and hopefully also Linux that can fully analyse the partitions and filesystems of as many kinds of systems as possible?

Comment: 1) Would bootable solutions be acceptable? (like recovery USB sticks). 2) Is command-line OK, or do you want a graphical user interface? 3) Analysis only, really? No need to remove/add partitions for instance?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Great questions I didn't think of - thanks! Yes I didn't think about bootable solutions at the time but that would indeed be an acceptable approach too. Command line with a TUI/curses interface would be OK. I'd settle for plain command line if there's nothing else, especially if it's more thorough than any prettier options. For my use case I would only need analysis and then go on to use a platform native tool for actually manipulating the partitions. I'll think about rewording my question based on your helpful feedback.